# dll loading using C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

My plugin is in c++ using Visual Studio.
We have several plugins in our product. our plugin exe is using spotabcXXXX.dll of one version which resides in our bin folder where exe present and another plugin is also using spotabcXXXX.dll of different version that resides in different location.

When we run our plugin standalone, it is using spotabcXXXX.dll resides in our bin. But when we run the whole product, our plugin is not referring spotabcXXXX.dll from our bin instead it is referring from different location.
Our product architecture:

```
C:\Spot
-->CommonFiles
   ----->spotabcXXXX.dll
-->OurPlugin
   ----->spotabcXXXX.dll
```

Since CommonFiles comes first(don't know whatever reason), our plugin takes spotabcXXXX.dll from CommonFiles.
We are not using LoadLibrary Programmatically.

Please help me how to load dll from our our bin.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to check against the DLL search order and how it relates to your 'whole product' and it's location; please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Answer (score 0):

This is just the kind of situation that [Side-by-Side Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/about-side-by-side-assemblies-) and [Activation Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/activation-contexts) can be used to address.

If your plugin loads `spotabcXXXX.dll` statically, you can define a SxS manifest for it that specifies a dependancy on the specific version of `spotabcXXXX.dll` you want. When your plugin is loaded, the OS loader will load and bind the dependant DLL that the manifest specifies.

If your plugin loads `spotabcXXXX.dll` dynamically, you can create an activation context that depends on the specific version of `spotabcXXXX.dll` you want, and then you can activate the context before calling `LoadLibrary()`.

Either way, your plugin will be bound to that version of `spotabcXXXX.dll` even if other portions of the calling process want to use a different version of `spotabcXXXX.dll`.